# Passing filtered @Bindable objects to multiple views in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, filter, swiftui, bindable

I’m trying to pass a filter array to multiple views, but the filtering is not working. If I remove the filter, you can pass the array to the next view, but that leads to another error during the ForEach loop. I've posted all the code below.

Does anyone know how you can pass a filter version of a @Bindable array? Also why can't I print sport.name and sport.isFavorite.description in the ForEach loop?

I’m using swiftUI on Xcode 11.0 beta 5.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct Sport: Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String
    var isFavorite = false
}

final class SportData: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var store =
        [
            Sport(name: "soccer",   isFavorite: false),
            Sport(name: "tennis",   isFavorite: false),
            Sport(name: "swimming", isFavorite: true),
            Sport(name: "running",  isFavorite: true)
    ]
}

struct Testing: View {
    @ObservedObject var sports = SportData()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TestingTwo(sports: $sports.store.filter({$0.isFavorite}))
        }
    }
}

struct TestingTwo: View {
    @Binding var sports : [Sport]

    var body: some View {t
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 10){
                ForEach($sports) { sport in
                    NavigationLink(destination: TestingThree(sport: sport)){
                        HStack {
                            Text(sport.name)
                            Spacer()
                            Text(sport.isFavorite.description)
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestingThree: View {
    @Binding var sport : Sport

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(sport.isFavorite.description)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.sport.isFavorite.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}


#if DEBUG
struct Testing_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Testing()
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Filtering in your case might be better placed in the navigation view, due to your binding requirements.

```
struct Testing: View {
    @ObservedObject var sports = SportData()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TestingTwo(sports: $sports.store)
        }
    }
}

struct TestingTwo: View {
    @Binding var sports : [Sport]
    @State var onlyFavorites = false

    var body: some View {t
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 10){
                ForEach($sports) { sport in
                    if !self.onlyFavorites || sport.value.isFavorite {
                        NavigationLink(destination: TestingThree(sport: sport)){
                            HStack {
                                Text(sport.value.name)
                                Spacer()
                                Text(sport.value.isFavorite.description)
                            }
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can switch the `isFavorite` state either within the action implementation of a button, or while specifying the integration of you `TestingTwo` view.

```
struct Testing: View {
    @ObservedObject var sports = SportData()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TestingTwo(sports: $sports.store, onlyFavorites: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding the second part of your question: Note the `value` addendum in the `ForEach` loop. You're dealing with as binding here (as `ForEach($sports)` indicates), hence `sport` is not an instance of `Sport`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to keep TestingTwo as a very reusable view. I've come up with a much better example of the problem I'm trying to solve. It can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57456832/filter-observable-variables-to-pass-to-reusable-views-swiftui

Answer (score 2):

You can't get a @Binding from a computed property, since the computed property is computed dynamically. A typical way to avoid this is to pass in ids of the sports objects and the data store itself, whereby you can access the sports items via id from the store.

If you really want to pass a `@Binding` in you have to remove the filter (pass in an actually backed array) and modfy the `ForEach` like the following:

```
  ForEach($sports.store) { (sport: Binding<Sport>) in
```

Comment: I came up with a better question for this topic. Would the same principle apply?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57456832/filter-observable-variables-to-pass-to-reusable-views-swiftui

Comment: I don't know about the other question, but what I can tell is that if you want to pass a binding in the source of truth cannot be dynamic, but rather must be stored inside an `ObservableObject`, as `State` somewhere or using the `.constant`-initializers.